# How to implement "supplant" in java

Tags: java, regex, substitution

"supplant() does variable substitution on the string. It scans through the string looking for expressions enclosed in { } braces. If an expression is found, use it as a key on the object, and if the key has a string value or number value, it is substituted for the bracket expression and it repeats."

More specifically, i am trying to do somethink like:

```
public static String supplant(CharSequence message, Map<String,Object> params)
```

I am trying to use a regex like  \{([\w]*)\} to capture the variables and then lookup the map and replace, but i couldn't write a regex that matches...

How would you implement supplant() in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is more commonly called *templating*.  There are many templating applications and libraries out there, but if you just want a quick-and-dirty solution, it can easily be implemented with regexes.

In many regex flavors you would use a built-in *callback* or *callout* mechanism, like PHP's `preg_replace_callback` function, or Perl's `/e` and `/ee` modifiers.  Java doesn't have anything like that, but it provides the API to let you implement it yourself.  Here's an example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String s = "Lorem ipsum {foo} impedit civibus ei pri, legimus\n" +
        "antiopam no {marco}, quo id everti forensibus maiestatis.";
    Map<String,Object> p = new HashMap<String,Object>()
    {{
      put("foo", "BAR");
      put("marco", "POLO!");
    }};
    System.out.printf("%s%n%n%s%n", s, supplant(s, p));
  }

  public static CharSequence supplant(CharSequence message, Map<String,Object> params)
  {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{(\\w+)\\}").matcher(message);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find())
    {
      m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
      String key = m.group(1);
      sb.append(params.get(key).toString());
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

Obviously this code leaves out some essential components (principally exception handling), but it demonstrates the main points of this technique:

1. Capture the content within the braces using parentheses, then access it by calling `group(1)` on the Matcher.
2. Use `appendReplacement(sb, "")` to append whatever text appeared between the previous match (if there was one) and the current one.
3. Look up the replacement and append it using StringBuffer's `append()` method.  (You *could* combine steps 2 and 3 by passing the replacement string as the second argument to `appendReplacement()`, but then you would have to watch out for dollar signs and backslashes in the string, which receive special treatment.  This way is much simpler.)
4. Use `appendTail(sb)` to append whatever's left after the last match.

Several people have published helper classes that let you accomplish this sort of task without having to write all that boilerplate code.  My favorite is Elliott Hughes's [Rewriter](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2004/07/java-implementation-of-rubys-gsub.html).

Answer (score 2):

Does it need to work with this exact format? Java already has built-in methods for substituting variables into strings.

See:

- [String#format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)
- [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)